# Python matrix loops

Tags: python, numpy

I have a python code which is expected to output a matrix exactly the same size of the input matrix. Output value at [i,j] should be equal to twice the sum of d[i-1,j] and d[i,j] and add the ouput at instance [i-1,j] to it. My code is as follows

```
import numpy as np

d=((2,3,5,6),(4,6,7,9),(8,4,7,3),(1,7,3,9),(5,8,2,6))
d=np.matrix(d)
r,c = np.shape(d)

temp=[]
y=[]
y.append([0,0,0,0])

for i in range (r-1):
    ro = d[i:i+2,:]     #fetch 2 rows at a time i.e. i and i+1
    for j in range (c):        
        col = ro[:,j]   #fetch 1 column of the row
        v1 = int(col[0])
        v2 = int(col[1]) 
        x = (v1+v2)*2+int(y[i][j])
        temp.append(x)
    y.append(temp)
y = np.matrix(y)
print y
```

Expected output is

```
[[0,0,0,0]
 [12,18,24,30]
 [36,38,52,54]
 [54,60,72,78]
 [66,90,82,108]]
```

But instead I get:

```
[[[0, 0, 0, 0]
  [12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 38, 52, 54, 30, 40, 44, 54, 24, 48, 34, 60]
  [12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 38, 52, 54, 30, 40, 44, 54, 24, 48, 34, 60]
  [12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 38, 52, 54, 30, 40, 44, 54, 24, 48, 34, 60]
  [12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 38, 52, 54, 30, 40, 44, 54, 24, 48, 34, 60]]]
```

Where is the error in my code?

Comment: Your definition of expected (and actual) output isn't sufficient. Right now I'd need to reverse engineer it and I don't feel like doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reset the `temp` accumulator each iteration of the outer loop. So the code would look:

```
...

for i in range (r-1):
    ro = d[i:i+2,:]     #fetch 2 rows at a time i.e. i and i+1
    temp = []  # <-------------
    for j in range (c):

        ...
```

---

The unexpected output you got with the **original code** is because of the way Python lists work: When you append an object to a Python list, only a reference to that object is stored, not a copy of the object. So after your loop has finished, the list `y` looks like:

```
[reference to [0,0,0,0],
 reference to list created at line 7,
 reference to list created at line 7,
 reference to list created at line 7,
 reference to list created at line 7]
```

So the last four references are all to same single object!

Answer (score 1):

This seems like something you can do with numpy slicing:

```
dout = np.zeros_like(d)
dout[1:,:] = (d[:-1] + d[1:])*2
dout[1:,:] += dout[:-1,:]
```

gives for `dout`:

```
matrix([[  0,   0,   0,   0],
        [ 12,  18,  24,  30],
        [ 36,  38,  52,  54],
        [ 54,  60,  72,  78],
        [ 66,  90,  82, 108]])
```

Comment: thank you @xnx..But can you help me how this will work for float values?

Comment: Just use `dout = np.zeros_like(d, dtype=float)` if you want `dout` to have floating point elements.